# How to run a tf2.0 model in Swift

Tags: python, swift, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I have a TF 2.0 model in TfLite form. How do I run this in swift? When I run it in python, it takes in an array of size (1, 96, 64, 1)... I have an array of this size in swift, how do I use this as input into the model? Thanks!!

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a complete course about using TensorFlow Lite on both Android and iOS on [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/device-based-models-tensorflow/). 3rd week of the course fully covers end-to-end integration TF Lite with Swift.

Comment: Will look at it. Don't they just cover image classification though? Isn't it different? Would you know how to pass in an array? Thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to follow up. Would really appreciate your help!